# Cómo guarar un array con tiempo (Horas) para luego aleatoriamente elegir uno?

Tags: php

Necesito elegir un tiempo aleatoriamente desde un array (entre 30 minutos y 1 hora 30 minutos) para eso hice la siguiente función, y la información será guardada en una tabla `time` de MySql:

```
function departure()
{
    $times = array('00:30:00', '00:36:00', '00:37:00', '00:38:00', '00:39:00', '00:40:00', '00:41:00', '00:42:00', '00:43:00', '00:44:00', '00:45:00', '00:46:00', '00:47:00', '00:48:00', '00:49:00', '00:50:00', '00:51:00', '00:52:00', '00:53:00', '00:44:00', '00:55:00', '00:56:00', '00:57', '00:58', '00:59', '01:01', '01:02', '01:03', '01:04:00', '01:05:00', '01:06:00', '01:07:00', '01:08:00', '01:09:00', '01:10:00', '01:11:00', '01:12:00', '01:13:00', '01:14:00', '01:15:00', '01:16:00', '01:17:00', '01:18:00', '01:19:00', '01:20:00', '01:21:00', '01:22:00', '01:23:00', '01:24:00', '01:25:00', '01:26:00', '01:27:00', '01:28:00', '01:29:00', '01:30:00');
    $random = array_rand($times, 1);
    return $random;
}
```

En la vista me muestra un número sin los dos puntos `:` y si coloco cada elemento sin comillas me da un error, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\Helpers\Code.php on line 12` me imagino que si el campo lo convierto en texto no tendré problema pero para mostrar el tiempo sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_rand` te devuelve la clave (índice) del array, no el valor del mismo, para obtener el valor puedes hacer algo así:

```
function departure()
{
    $times = array('00:30:00', '00:36:00', '00:37:00', '00:38:00', '00:39:00', '00:40:00', '00:41:00', '00:42:00', '00:43:00', '00:44:00', '00:45:00', '00:46:00', '00:47:00', '00:48:00', '00:49:00', '00:50:00', '00:51:00', '00:52:00', '00:53:00', '00:44:00', '00:55:00', '00:56:00', '00:57', '00:58', '00:59', '01:01', '01:02', '01:03', '01:04:00', '01:05:00', '01:06:00', '01:07:00', '01:08:00', '01:09:00', '01:10:00', '01:11:00', '01:12:00', '01:13:00', '01:14:00', '01:15:00', '01:16:00', '01:17:00', '01:18:00', '01:19:00', '01:20:00', '01:21:00', '01:22:00', '01:23:00', '01:24:00', '01:25:00', '01:26:00', '01:27:00', '01:28:00', '01:29:00', '01:30:00');
    $random = array_rand($times, 1);
    return $times[$random];
}
```

---

### Otra forma de hacerlo, usando objetos

Si lo que interesa es una hora aleatoria entre las `00:30:00` y la `01:30:00` puedes implementar el siguiente código basado en objetos.

Está todo comentado en el código.

```
#Creamos un objeto inicializado a las 00:30:00
$mTime = new DateTime('today 00:30:00');
#Modificamos el objeto inicial, con un valor aleatorio
#pero dentro de un rango entre 0 y 60 minutos
#o sea, un minuto cualquiera entre las 00:30 y la 01:30
$mTime->modify(random_int(0,60).' Minutes');
#Usamos format para mostrar el dato
echo $mTime->format('H:i:s');
```

Aquí no trabajas con  un array físico de horas, sino con una hora generada de forma aleatoria.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias! sólo cambié $ítems por $times

Comment: Sí, ha sido un *typo* de mi parte, ahora edito.

Comment: No hay problema, gracias... Eso pasa!